# How to make an AWS SAM app highly available and fault tolerant

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-serverless

I have developed a SAM app that takes incoming emails submissions, listens to specific SQS queues for the incoming data type, parses the payload via the correct python Lambda worker function and submits data down the line into another SQS queue for further action.  I have deployed this stack from PyCharm using a SAM YAML template.

[image]

I need to improve the app with better disaster recovery options for fault tolerance.  I don't believe I can improve the inbound email receiving function through SES, so that will be a single point of failure (if SES fails in us-east-1, my app fails).  However, I'd like for the SQS messages to be delivered to the Parser Worker functions in multiple regions.

Scenario:

- email1 comes into SES and is stored in the correct S3 key
- S3 triggers event notification to Parser1 SQS queue
- Parser1 SQS message is picked up in a load-balanced manner by one of multiple Parser1 Worker functions deployed in multiple Regions (us-east1a, us-east-2a, etc) thus providing disaster recovery and fault tolerance

Is there a way to distribute the SQS message in a load-balanced type of scenario to multiple Lambdas deployed in multiple regions so that I don't have the single point of failure in one stack in one region?

I have the app running in production in its single-stack deployment.  I am concerned about redundancy and single points of failure.  I am not sure how to improve this situation, so have not tried anything yet.

Comment: [AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/security-resilience.html) runs your function in multiple Availability Zones to ensure that it is available to process events in case of a service interruption in a single zone. Unless your function is connected to virtual private cloud (VPC).

If you use an AWS service, they are usually highly-available. So I am kinda confused, what you are trying accomplish?

Comment: I have edited my question to be region specific.  I am looking for a way to improve its fault tolerance.  The main question is about load-balancing message delivery from SQS to the Lambda worker functions in multiple regions.

Comment: Just thinking about this, I think you need an ALB. By using an ALB, you can set the rule as geography base then you can route to the correct SQS. Is that what you were trying to accomplish?